# Why declare named function before DOM event fires?

Tags: javascript

I am reading Jon Duckett's book "Javascript and jQuery." In the section about event listeners he states:

> If you use a named function when the event fires on your chosen DOM node, write that function first. (You could also use an anonymous function)

And follows it up with this code:

```
function checkUsername() {
  var elMsg = document.getElementById('feedback');
  if (this.value.length < 5) {
    elMsg.textContent = 'Username must be 5 characters or more';
  } else {
    elMsg.textContent = '';
  }
}

var elUsername = document.getElementById('username');
elUsername.addEventListener('blur', checkUsername, false);
```

Since the interpreter is going to go through and look for all named functions and variables before is processes the script, why does it matter that the function comes before it is passed into addEventListener?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter, the function declaration is hoisted anyway.

Comment: I guess the recommendation is made so that when you see that on blur we run checkUsername, you have an idea of what that means exactly.

Comment: I think it is just a coding style tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter as far as script execution is concerned, but it helps to keep a consistent ordering for maintainability, which is really just a way of saying that it makes the code easier to read and understand.

In JavaScript, function and variable declarations are always hoisted to the top of their containing scope, so it really doesn't matter where the function is written.

I recommend an order of:

1. directives
2. variable declaration
3. function declaration
4. variable instantiation
5. code execution

Using this order also allows developers to easily switch a function declaration into a variable instantiation, such as:

```
function foo() {
    ...do stuff...
}
```

to

```
var foo;
foo = switch ? function () {
        ...do stuff...
    } : function () {
        ...do other stuff...
    };
```

And, it helps to prevent silly errors from occurring where an author mistakes the scope of a function or variable.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks for the writeup on best practices :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter for functionality (as declarations are hoisted), but it's good practise to define things before using them.